# How do I create a template file for the custom node view mode?

Tags: theming, entities

I am using Drupal 8, and I created a new view mode for the *News page* content type, in the custom display settings section.

> [image]

How can I create a template file for this view mode?

Comment: Hey Rick what exactly is unclear in template naming suggestions? What have you tried so far? Please help to clarify by expanding your question and providing more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the D8 docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions), you'd need to create a file in your your custom theme with this naming convention:

`node--[type|nodeid]--[viewmode].html.twig`

So if I had a content type of `person` and a view mode of `Teaser` my template name would be `node--person--teaser.html.twig`. Be sure to follow the machine name patterns if you're using spaces in your custom view mode.

Generally speaking, I like to put it in a `templates/node` directory of my theme so that other devs can find it quickly. Whether you copy the base node template (`core/modules/node/templates/node.html.twig`) or start from scratch is up to you.

Also, if you turn on [theme debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates), Drupal will output in HTML comments a list of template name suggestions, starting from most specific to least specific filenames.